# UTF-8 encoded JSON file, trying to parse with JSON module - wide character

Tags: perl, utf-8

I have a pretty simple script in Perl:

```
use JSON;

use open qw/ :std :encoding(utf8) /;

#my $ref = JSON::decode_json($json_contents);

my $path = "/home/chambres/web/x.org/public_html/cgi-bin/links/admin/booking_import/import/file.json";

my $json_contents = slurp_utf8_file($path);

my $ref =  JSON->new->utf8->decode($json_contents);

sub slurp_utf8_file {

  my @back;
  #open my $in,  '<:encoding(UTF-8)',  $_[0]  or die $!;
  open my $in,  "<$_[0]" or die $!;
    while (<$in>) {
      push @back, $_
    }
  close ($in);

  return join("", @back);
}
```

The file is encoded in UTF-8 in Notepad++:

[image]

...yet when I run my script I get:

```
perl test.cgi
Wide character in subroutine entry at test.cgi line 11.
```

Line 11 is:

```
my $ref =  JSON->new->utf8->decode($json_contents);
```

I'm baffled as to what I'm doing wrong. Maybe I just need a break! Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Aren't you attempting double UTF-8 decode? You already decode UTF-8 in the slurp, why would you need `->utf8` on the JSON object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to double decode UTF-8:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

open(my $fh,  '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $ARGV[0]) or die $!;
my @lines = <$fh>;
close($fh) or die $!;

# Wide character in subroutine entry at dummy.pl line 14.
my $ref = JSON->new->utf8->decode(join('', @lines));

# OK, no warning.
my $ref = JSON->new->decode(join('', @lines));

print Dumper($ref);

exit 0;
```

Test run

```
$ cat dummy.json
{
   "path": "ä⁈"
}

# with ->utf8
$ perl dummy.pl dummy.json
Wide character in subroutine entry at dummy.pl line 14.

# without ->utf8
$ perl dummy.pl dummy.json
$VAR1 = {
          'path' => "\x{e4}\x{2048}"
        };
```

Comment: Ah man  - sometimes you just need an extra pair of eyes to look over it! I think this came from trying to use File::Slurp::read_file, but that apparently isn't good with utf8 - so I moved over to reading the file myself, but guess I didn't take that part out as well. Thanks for saving my sanity :)

Comment: @AndrewNewby It is recommended to use [File::Slurper](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurper) instead which has much more straightforward functions. From that you can use read_binary to read the bytes as-is, and then use a standard UTF-8 decoding json decoder.

Comment: @Grinnz thanks for the recommendation. I'll try and remember that for the next project :) (for now, the method I'm using is working as needed, so not much point including a whole extra module :))